# How do I save an identical picture as different names embedded in an Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch, zip

I usually save pictures embedded in an Excel by making its zip then refer xl/media.
But with this method, identical picture is treated as one picture and doesn't grant different names.
How can I avoid this specification?

The following are the current procedure I wrote on .bat:

1. Convert .xlsx file to .zip file
2. Extract images from \xl\media\

In step 2, if .xlsx contains the exact the same image more than one, it's counted just one file in \xl\media.
For example, when 6 images (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5) are attached on .xlsx, 5 images (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) are put at \xl\media.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I described the detail.